# A little problem about a CSS GRID "Hover" dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I came with a new basics problem, I’m stuck on it for a long time now…  I tried with CSS GRID to make a hoverable dropdown menu, but after a few tries I think I misunderstand something about the parents and child.

What I tried at first was to make an `<ul <.dropdown>` behind my `<li<a #shop…..>` But I don’t know why I can’t hover #Shop, I can hover all the menu but not #Shop.

Same when I tried to encapsulate this same  into the <li <#Shop>, but same problem.

So I tried an other solution which at first, appeared to be clean, I create my dropdown menu behind the `<ul>` of my navbar, create some row behind the nav and hide my 3 dropdown line behind #Shop, but once again #Shop doesn’t trigger my hover… I think this time is because they are not in the same blocks.

Clearly I think something is wrong with my understanding why can’t I hover the ID #Shop ? And how can I link #Shop and his dropdown together?
Thanks again for your help.

My Code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: ;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
  /*--------------------------*\
  |          BANNIERE          |
  \---------------------------*/
.Banniere {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(image/abstr.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -2;
}
.Banniere h2 {
  padding: 250px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: ;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -2;
}
  /*--------------------------*\
  |          HEADER            |
  \---------------------------*/
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row: 1;
  gap: 10px;
  z-index: 500;
}

/*Alignement et ecartement*/
nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: orange;
  transition: 1s;
}
.logo {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.recherche {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 300px;
}
.saisie {
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}
.search {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  width: 110%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.bouton-saisie {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  right: -169px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 94, 0);
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
/*--------------------------*\
|          DROPDOWN          |
\---------------------------*/
#dropdown {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;

}
#Shop:hover #dropdown {
  display: grid;
}
#drop{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-column: 4;
  text-align: right;

}
#dropdown ul li a:hover {
  color: orange;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#dropdown li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.ss1 {
  grid-row:1;
}
.ss2 {
  grid-row:2;
}
.ss3 {
  grid-row:3;
}

/*--------------------------*\
|          GRID PROD         |
\---------------------------*/
.texte {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 60vh;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 90vh;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  
}
.texte h2 {
  font-family: ;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "box1 box2 box3 box3"
    "box1 box4 box5 box6";
}
.article img{
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.article img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.02, 1.02);
  border-color: orange;
}
.article img{
  border: 4px solid grey;
  /*width: 50%;
  height: auto;*/
}
.article img:hover{
  border: 4px solid orange;
}
.box1 {
  grid-area: box1;
}
.box2 {
  grid-area: box2;
}
.box3 {
  grid-area: box3;

}
.box4 {
  grid-area: box4;
}
.box5 {
  grid-area: box5;

}
.box6 {
  grid-area: box6;
}
.deroulant {
  /*Hamburger*/
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: rgb(245, 149, 94);
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*Pour qu'il soit dans sa box*/
  cursor: pointer; /*Pour pointer dessus*/
  text-align: right;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  font-size: 26px;
}
.button-more a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;

}
.button-more a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
/*--------------------------*\
|          SCRIPT            |
\---------------------------*/
nav.scroll ul {
  /*Class du script*/
  background: black;
}
/*--------------------------*\
|          FOOTER            |
\---------------------------*/
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-container {
  background-color: grey;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -620px;
}
.reseaux {
  justify-self: center;
}
.reseaux ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.reseau ul li a {
}

.left-content {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
.left-content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left-content ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: ;
}

.middle-content {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
.middle-content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.middle-content ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: ;
}
.container-cr {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -620px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
/*--------------------------*\
|          MEDIA             |
\---------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 580px) {
  .deroulant {
    display: flex;
  }
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 15%;
    justify-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  .menu {
    max-height: 20em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .recherche {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .deroulant:hover nav ul li {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>PharmaTech</title>
        <meta name="description de la page" content="A compléter pour le referencement"><!--Description du site, apparait notamment dans la description google-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, aussi pour le referencement"><!--index du site, apparait notamment dans la description google-->
        <link rel="icon" href="image/Phoenix-detoure.png"><!--Icone de l'onglet de site-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!--toujours afficher l'entiereté de la page peu importe la largeur-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Projet.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="deroulant">
                    <label for="hamburger">&#9776</label>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <img class="logo" src="image/Phoenix-detoure.png" alt="logo" >
                        <div class="recherche">
                            <form>
                                <div class="saisie">
                                    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Recherche" name="Recherche">
                                    <button class="bouton-saisie" type="submit"></button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <li><a id="home" href="Projet.html"> Home </a></li>
                        <li><a id="Shop" href="Shop.html"> Shop</a> </li>
                        <li><a id="login" href="about.html"> Login </a></li>
                        <li><a id="signup" href="Contact.html"> Sign-up </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="dropdown">
                        <ul id="drop">
                            <li class="ss1"><a href="#"> NanoMachine</a></li>
                            <li class="ss2"><a href="#"> BioPuce</a></li>
                            <li class="ss3"><a href="#"> Prothèse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="Banniere">
            <h2>Slogan</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="texte">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Titre</h2>
                <p>Ligne d'articles 1</p>
                <div class="article">
                    <a href="exo.html" class="box1"><img src="prod/exo.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                    <a href="arm1.html" class="box2"><img src="prod/arm1.jpg"height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                    <a href="heal.html" class="box3"><img src="prod/heal.jpg"height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                    <a href="lungs.html" class="box4"><img src="prod/lungs.jpg"height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                    <a href="arm2.html" class="box5"><img src="prod/arm2.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                    <a href="drone.html" class="box6"><img src="prod/drone.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" alt="Exo"></img></a>
                </div>
                <div class="button-more">
                    <a href="Shop.html">Plus d'article...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="footer-container">
                <div class="left-content">
                    <ul>
                        <h3>Nous trouver</h3>
                        <li><a id="home" href="#"> ? </a></li>
                        <li><a id="Shop" href="#"> Nous trouver </a></li>
                        <li><a id="About" href="about.html"> A propos de nous </a></li>
                        <li><a id="Contact" href="Contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="middle-content">
                    <ul>
                        <h3>Moyens de paiement</h3>
                        <li><a id="home" href="Projet.html"> ? </a></li>
                        <li><a id="Shop" href="Shop.html"> ? </a></li>
                        <li><a id="About" href="about.html"> ?</a></li>
                        <li><a id="Contact" href="Contact.html"> ? </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="reseaux">
                    <h3>Nos reseaux</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><img src="image/Twitter.ico" wheight="25" height="25" alt="Redirection sous forme de logo vers twitter" ></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><img src="image/Facebook.ico" wheight="25" height="25" alt="Redirection sous forme de logo vers Facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="instagram"><img src="image/Instagram.ico"wheight="25" height="25"  alt="Redirection sous forme de logo vers instagram"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <div class="container-cr">
            <p>Created by Antoine & Alexandre 2020 copyright</p>
        </div>

    </body>
    <script>  
       window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        // Setup the new requestAnimationFrame()
       let timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
       // Run our scroll functions
       let nav = document.querySelector('nav'); /*Selection de la class voulus grace à query*/
       if (document.querySelector('header').getBoundingClientRect().top !== 0) {
        nav.classList.add('scroll');
        } else {
       nav.classList.remove('scroll');
        }      
   });
       }, false);
   </script>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Raz7/pen/zYKoJzY)

Comment: Your html is wrong in `.reseaux` as you are not opening `ul` and `li` but just closing your `li` after your links. Probably a bad copy / paste. Plus this JS, is incorrect: `document.getElementById("").classList.add('down');` as you dont select any element, it cannot add class `.down`.  You are also setting `li` out of `ul` or `ol` like in your `#dropdown`. And finaly that is wrong as img is a single tag: `<a href="#"><img src="prod/exo.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"></a></img>`

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Indeed, I don’t know what i’ve done with .reseau, but thanks to you it’s solved now.
For the JS I have tried to manually put a class just to check if it could solve my hover problem, but it didn’t apparently. 
Thanks again for all your pointer, I will keep that in mind for the next. About the hover I add the ul to my dropdown, which I didn’t do before because I wanted to avoid merging the ul CSS from my navbar to this one, but I get it it’s not something we should do, anyway, even so I got the same issue, I cant dropdown from #shop.

Comment: Please update your code with correction you made

Comment: It's done with the new one, I hope I didn't misunderstand what you said before espacially the part about the img functionnality.